# Generating whole numbers using recursion without comprehensions

Tags: python

```
    Even_numb(8, 4)
    [8, 10, 12, 14] %figure 1
```

im trying to write a function called Even_numb that is supposed to return a list of whole numbers starting with the smallest going to the biggest as seen in figure 1. I tried using the range function but i was not allowed to use it for this example. I also have to use recursion without using comperhension. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think you mean "integer" instead of "whole numbers" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
def gen(a,b):
    while True:
        print(a)
        a += 2
        c.append(0)
        if len(c) == b:
           break

def Even_numb(a,b):
    c = []
    gen(a,b)

# Example Code
Even_numb(4,5)
```

Comment: I added recursions. Welcome